# SQL Where Condition that ignores null and blank spaces

Tags: mysql, sql

```
insert into Dim_Business_Line(Business_Line_Code,Business_Line_Name) 
select max(tbl.Business_Line_Code) as Business_Line_Code, tbl.Business_Line_Name 
from temp_Business_Line tbl 
LEFT JOIN Dim_Business_Line bl ON  tbl.Business_Line_Name = bl.Business_Line_Name  
where IFNULL(tbl.Business_Line_Name, '')<>''  
AND bl.Business_Line_Name IS NULL  
Group By tbl.Business_Line_Name;
```

In this code, in where conditon IFNULL(tbl.Business_Line_Name, ' ')<>' '  is where i am stuck, `for this my trainer said it is a condition that ignores null and blank spaces .Can anyone explain How?`

Comment: The expression makes sure to only select rows with a Business_Line_Name. If Business_Line_Name is the empty string, the row doesn't get selected, and if Business_Line_Name is null, it doesn't get selected either. It would suffice to apply `where tbl.Business_Line_Name <> ''`, because this exludes nulls already. So the `IFFNULL` is just for readability maybe, by making the null thing explicit, but for this I'd prefer `where tbl.Business_Line_Name <> '' and tbl.Business_Line_Name is not null`.

Comment: Blank spaces are not considered here, by the way. If `tbl.Business_Line_Name = '   '`, the row gets selected. You can use `TRIM` to treat these as empty strings, too.

Answer (score 0):

`IFNULL(tbl.Business_Line_Name, '')` returns `''` string if `tbl.Business_Line_Name` is `NULL`. `<>` operator is excluding all `''` strings.

Comment: `''` (the empty string) actually. `' '` is a string containing a blank, which is something different.

Comment: I don't know what happened. The original question I answered had a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

More the `bl.Business_Line_Name` being NULL and still having a JOIN on just this value is slightly surprising.

When tbl.Business_Line_Name is NULL or is not NULL the joining is different.
A LEFT join would use a subset.

Using IFNULL makes reading, and the entire logic, quite difficult.

```
LEFT JOIN Dim_Business_Line bl ON  tbl.Business_Line_Name = bl.Business_Line_Name  
WHERE IFNULL(tbl.Business_Line_Name, '') <> ''  
AND bl.Business_Line_Name IS NULL
```

I cannot guess what you are querying. It would actually imply:

```
LEFT JOIN Dim_Business_Line bl ON  tbl.Business_Line_Name = bl.Business_Line_Name  
WHERE tbl.Business_Line_Name IS NOT NULL
AND tbl.Business_Line_Name <> ''  
AND bl.Business_Line_Name IS NULL
```

But that would yield no records. Maybe an OUTER join or an OR. No idea.

About spaces, you might use the TRIM function.